# What's the best way to use external artifacts as input to a buildbot build?

Tags: buildbot

I am using buildbot to build a firmware image from a bunch of other pre-built artifacts.  The pre-built artifacts are built using a different system(jenkins) which is not under my control.  I want to automatically kick off a new build when new artifacts are available.  Since it's not under my control I can't add anything to "trigger" buildbot.  I need a poll-based approach.  What's the best way to do something like this with buildbot?  Should I treat the pre-built artifacts as "source" and make a JenkinsPoller that extends PollingChangeSource?  Should I create a new scheduler that polls jenkins?

Answer (score 2):

So I ended up implementing a PollingChangeSource called JenkinsPoller with code lifted from [GoogleCodeAtomPoller](http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/cfg-changesources.html#chsrc-GoogleCodeAtomPoller).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a PBSource in buildbot and have Jenkins call `buildbot sendchange` as the last step after creating its artifacts.

```
buildbot sendchange --master {MASTERHOST}:{PORT} --auth {USER}:{PASS}
    --who {USER} {FILENAMES..}
```

see: http://buildbot.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/cmdline.html

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any control over the Jenkins install so I can't add anything.